# Angularjs and jQuery function

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I can not call id if the script is in the ng-view. and how a little input in the can in the given function?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      $(this).addClass('used');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('used');
      $(this).addClass('noused');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div ng-view>//here there is a form input</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

function for input is not running. but if it does not use a route that is in the ng-view. The input function can be run.
please, give a solution that can still use these functions

Comment: Have you tried to use `$postLink` in the myAppController? $postLink is triggered when all the dom in the page is rendered, so inside that function, you can look up the element by its id.

Comment: Why don't you just use the built-in form validation functionality?

Comment: I Want to give effect to animate to review validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view may not be constructed by the time `document.ready()` is called, so it may not find the `input` to attach the `blur` event to.

So instead, you can use [ngBlur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) on the `input` element itself to call your function. Something like:

```
<input type="text" ng-blur="doSomething(this)">

<script>
function doSomething(me) {
    if ($(me).val()) {
      $(me).removeClass('notused').addClass('used');
    } else {
      $(me).removeClass('used').addClass('notused');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried using your script,

but the function of -->>  if ($(this).val()) { --> not be run, nothing happened

Comment: I try, And Appear Error: e.nodeName is undefined  ? on console log, and did not happen on the input

Comment: Sounds like something else in your code or HTML is causing that error.